# Fragments android orientation loss of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

I'm having a struggle with fragment loss on orientation change.
At first my fragments seem to be responding well to orientation changes and nothing is wrong.
But the exception is when I navigate back to a previously made fragment. Since I'm checking that in my fragmenthandler activity.

I chose to use a big if statement instead of switch cases, since that was more within the grasp of my knowledge. The handling of the if statements works correctly, have been debugging it with log statements and nothing seems to be wrong there. Below is the code for the handling of fragments, pre-used or create a new one.

```
public void fragmentHandle(Fragment fl, Fragment fr, String tl, String tr) {
    Fragment cFragLeft = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_left);
    Fragment cFragRight = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_right);

    Fragment checkLeft = manager.findFragmentByTag(tl);
    Fragment checkRight = manager.findFragmentByTag(tr);

    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

    if (cFragLeft != null && cFragRight != null && checkLeft != null
            && checkRight != null) {
        ft.detach(cFragRight).detach(cFragLeft).attach(fr).attach(fl)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    } else if (cFragLeft != null && cFragRight != null && checkLeft == null
            && checkRight == null) {
        ft.detach(cFragLeft).detach(cFragRight)
                .add(R.id.fragment_left, fl, tl)
                .add(R.id.fragment_right, fr, tr).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    } else if (cFragLeft != null && cFragRight != null && checkLeft == null
            && checkRight != null) {
        ft.detach(cFragLeft).detach(cFragRight).attach(fr)
                .add(R.id.fragment_left, fl, tl).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    } else if (cFragLeft != null && cFragRight != null
            && checkRight == null && checkLeft != null) {
        ft.detach(cFragLeft).detach(cFragRight).attach(fl)
                .add(R.id.fragment_right, fr, tr).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    } else {
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_left, fl, tl).add(R.id.fragment_right, fr, tr)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

When I change orientation, and then navigating back to a previously saved fragment (first if statement) both of my left and right fragments show blank screens. This happens only when case 1 is called, it doesn't seem to remember the fragments that were there, even though the fragmentmanager found them by tag.

I've also been checking my onCreate, and it's shown below.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // super.onCreate
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_handler);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentHandle(nFragLeft, nFragRight, "menuMain", "main");
    }

}
```

Also including a button statement just for completion's sake. Haven't been using onClickListeners and not really sure whether I should prefer this over xml onClick or not.

```
    public void sendDestination(View v) {
    nFragLeft = menudestFrag;
    nFragRight = destFrag;
    String tagLeft = "menuDestination";
    String tagRight = "destination";

    fragmentHandle(nFragLeft, nFragRight, tagLeft, tagRight);
}
```

Is there any way to work around this? Only happens after changing orientation.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your activity is reacreated when orientation is changed.

you can solve this problem adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in manifest(prevent to recreate activity when orientation was changed):

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.MyActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: I know I can do it by changing the android manifest, but that's not a legit way of handling fragment in my opinion. It just prevents android from using it's native orientation handling.

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the fragments, since android seems to be able to find them by tag, yet just doesn't seem to have saved the data of that particular fragment.

I've also found a different workaround, in case I don't need to preserve any data inside my fragments, just by removing and adding the fragments instead of attaching and detaching, but then I'm not able to preserve data.

Comment: I've tried your solution nevertheless, but faced an immediate problem with it. I've been making a dynamic UI, meaning it switches from one pane to two panes (port to land) and vice versa.

With this solution it doesn't change the layout, since it's not recreated. I'm calling the xml layout through onCreateView's, hence I think this solution is not appropriate for me ;/

Comment: thanks, your point is very good. you raise a problem in my app. i have another suggestion for you , i did not tryit but i think will work.. check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) onconfigurationChange attach/add/repalce your last fragment from backstack. hope this help.

Comment: If it was just to go back one layer it would work, but I'm using a custom breadcrumbs navigation idea, in which I should be able to go up 4 layers (max) at once. Still thanks for your input though.